# PHP late static binding doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, late-static-binding, static-binding

While coding and using late static binding in PHP I found some strange behaviour. A child object created with `static()` in its parent class can access the private methods of its parent.

Here's an example:

```
class Attachment
{
  public static function createFromFile($file)
  {
    $attachment = new static();
    echo get_class($attachment) . PHP_EOL;
    $attachment->loadFromFile($file);
  }

  private function loadFromFile($file)
  {
    echo 'attachment';
  }
}

class PictureAttachment extends Attachment
{
  //...
}

PictureAttachment::createFromFile('example.txt');
```

Output:

```
PictureAttachment
attachment
```

Is this a correct behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yes*, this is correct. The class that is calling the private method is the same that is declaring it. It doesn't matter that it may or may not instantiate a child class. You just can't have any code in the child class calling the private method of the parent.

In other words:

```
class Foo {

    protected function bar() {
        $this->baz();
    }

    private function baz() { }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

    protected function bar() {
        parent::bar();   // <-- works
        parent::baz();   // <-- doesn't work
    }

}
```

Comment: For further clarification: visibility works on class-level not on object-level.